# How do I group, restructure and count array of object data based on another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of object:

```
let attend = [
    {
        style: 'Big',
        date: '03/01/2016'
    },
    {
        style: 'Big',
        date: '03/01/2016'
    },
    {
        style: 'Small',
        date: '04/01/2016'
    },
    {
        style: 'Small',
        date: '03/01/2016'
    },
    {
        style: 'Big',
        date: '01/01/2016'
    }
]
```

and this array: `let now = ['01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016']`

which I'd like to use in comparing, counting, and formating the array of object BASED on the date, in summary, I'd want the result to look like this:

```
     {
            name: 'Big',
            data: [1, 0, 2]
     },
     {
            name: 'Small',
            data: [0, 0, 2]
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for grouping date in date key and name

```js
let attend = [
{
    style: 'Big',
    date: '03/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'Big',
    date: '03/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'Small',
    date: '04/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'Small',
    date: '03/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'Small',
    date: '01/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'Big',
    date: '01/01/2016'
},
{
    style: 'myTestDear',
    date: '05/01/2016'
}
]
let now = ['01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016']
function makeZeroArray(array, index) {
for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    array.push(0)
}
return array;
}
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < attend.length; i++) {
if (result.findIndex(x => x.name === attend[i].style) == -1) {
    result.push({
        name: attend[i].style,
        data: makeZeroArray([], now.length)
    })
}
var resIndex = result.findIndex(x => x.name === attend[i].style)
var myIndex = now.findIndex(nowDate => nowDate === attend[i].date);
if (myIndex != -1)
    result[resIndex].data[myIndex] += 1;
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mohammad, how can I make it be the same length as the variable 'now' like all having the same data length? I really appreciate it.

Comment: sorry! i dont see now array and i think you should make grouping all data in attend array. but im update my code and use it. its OK! and make result for extra data in attend array. and dont show for example { name: 'Small', data: [ 1, 0, 1, '-1': NaN ] },

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and group your data based on `style` and increase the count of given date.

```js
const attend = [ { style: 'Big', date: '03/01/2016' }, { style: 'Big', date: '03/01/2016' }, { style: 'Small', date: '03/01/2016' }, { style: 'Small', date: '03/01/2016' }, { style: 'Big', date: '01/01/2016' } ],
      now = ['01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016'],
      
      result = Object.values(attend.reduce((r, {style, date}) => {
        r[style] = r[style] || { 
              name: style, 
              data: Array(now.length).fill(0)
           };
        const index = now.findIndex(option => option === date);
        
        r[style].data[index] += 1;
        return r;
      },{}));
      
console.log(result);
```